# YouTube Data API 'youtube#channel' query: the 'brandingSettings.image' is no longer available as of 11-11-2020?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Using the YouTube Data API, doing a 'youtube#channel' query, the `brandingSettings.image` is no longer available as of 11-11-2020? Has anyone else noticed this? Will there any way to get the `brandingSettings.image.bannerImageUrl` going forward?

This is the API URL that used to return a channel's `bannerImageUrl`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id=UCXGgrKt94gR6lmN4aN3mYTg&key=[your key]`.

Thanks,
-Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the official API revision history doc specifies exactly that (albeit with a different date):

> [**September 9, 2020**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-9,-2020)
>
> This update covers the following API changes. All changes will go into effect on or after 9 September 2020, the date of this announcement. With that in mind, developers should no longer rely on any of the API features listed below.
>
> - The following API resources, methods, parameters, and resource properties are deprecated immediately and will stop working on or after the date of this announcement:
>
>   - The following [`channel`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) resource properties:
>
>     - The `brandingSettings.image` object and all of its child properties
>
> [...]

This announcement indicates no replacement for the deprecated and removed `Channel` resource properties. Neither the official spec of [`brandingSettings.image`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#brandingSettings.image).

Moreover, as far as I know, there's no other API endpoint that'll provide those properties one way or the other.

Comment: Any idea why they'd deprecate this? Seems like scraping is the only option now, and there doesn't seem to be a good reason for just disabling this entirely seen as it's useful.

Comment: Have no idea why they did this. True also that haven't dug the Internet. It may well be possible that hints be found on the company's support site.