# YouTube Data API channel brandingSettings image

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

How can I retrieve channel wide image (not thumbnails) with latest YouTube Data API?

There used to be `brandingSettings.image`, which worked fine; however, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#properties), it's now deprecated.

Comment: I just [answered to this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64793243/8327971). Unfortunately, negatively.