# Channel brandingSettings image YT API deprecated

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question related to YT API `brandingSettings.image` which is now deprecated. I used it to retrieve the channel banner image `brandingSettings.getImage().getBannerImageUrl()`. Is there any other way to retrieve the banner image for channel using YT API?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [YouTube Data API 'youtube#channel' query: the 'brandingSettings.image' is no longer available as of 11-11-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792572/youtube-data-api-youtubechannel-query-the-brandingsettings-image-is-no-lon)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes I already saw that question, but unfortunately, it doesn't give me an answer to the question since this is deprecated, is there replacement endpoint to retrieve this piece of information(banner image for channel)?

Comment: Sorry, that answer responds precisely to your question: quote from it: *This announcement indicates no replacement for the deprecated and removed `Channel` resource properties. Neither the official spec of [`brandingSettings.image`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#brandingSettings.image).  Moreover, as far as I know, there's no other API endpoint that'll provide those properties one way or the other.* The answer is negative, indeed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if there is a replacement, probably that would be mentioned in YT API docs.